# Jquery html() instead of val()

Tags: php, jquery, html-select

I have a select list skinned by a jquery plugin. the problem is that when I choose a select element, the value of the select field before post id val() and I want it to be the html() between  . but if I put html() instead of val() I get the entire html of the select list optgroup.

the part of the jquery where I have problems:

```
$(this).height(selectBoxHeight).change(function(){
    selectBoxSpanInner.text($(this).val()).parent().addClass('changed');
});
```

(here I set the val)
and the html:

```
<select name="123_cat" class ="styled">  
   <?php foreach($subcategories['categories'] as $sc) { ?>
   <optgroup label="<?php echo $sc['name']; ?>">
    <?php foreach ($sc['subcategories'] as $ss){?>                              
             <option id = "123_cat[]" value="<?php echo $ss['sid']; ?>" <?php if (isset($_POST['123_cat'])) { if($ss['sid'] == $_POST['123_cat']) echo 'selected = "selected"';} else { if(in_array($ss['sid'], $the_subcategories)) echo 'selected = "selected"'; } ?>><?php echo $ss['name']; ?></option>
        <?php }?>
```

How can I get the text between `<option>` `</option>` selected onclick instead of the value of it?

Comment: is this multiple select or just single select.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried using

```
$("option:selected", this).text()
```

Comment: $(this).text() is listing me all the options of the select after i select one